# Handsontable, disable edit but allow values from drop down for cells

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable where I have a column with cells of type drop-down.

The problem is that I can use the delete key to remove the cell value, which is not an option in the drop -down and should not be allowed!

How can I either disable the delete button for that column, alternatively disable all editing but still allow changing the drop down value for the column?

Here is a link [to a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/handsontable-drop-down-delete)

Thanks!

Comment: please share component js and component html

Comment: I've added a stackblitz now.

Comment: @mottosson I wrote an anwser below. Does this help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to block deletion is to use `beforeChange` hook provided by Handsontable and discard change if the new value is `null`.

In your table settings, add following property :

```
beforeChange: (changes, source) => {
  // changes is an array of change => [[row, col, oldValue, newValue], ...]
  if (changes[0][1] === 1 && changes[0][3] === null) {
    changes[0] = null;
  }
}
```

This will work if there is only one deletion at the same time. But if you allow user to edit more than one cell at a time, you will have to handle each change in a loop. But i think you get the idea.

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/handsontable-drop-down-delete-jorph5?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Ideally Handsontable would support only allowing the values in the drop-down. But you've answered my question. Thanks!